# Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).flickity is not a function

Tags: jquery, wordpress, flickity

So I was trying to add flickity to my website with this code here:

```
jQuery('.main-carousel').flickity({
  // options
  cellAlign: 'left',
  contain: true
});
```

It was working yesterday but for some reason today the slider won't work at all and I don't know why. Here is my website for reference : https://fitnesslore.dreamhosters.com/

I have tried every tutorial on the internet and nothing has worked so far.

Comment: seems like a Wordpress installation. how are you loading the `flickity` library? it is telling you that your custom js code which is using it is being called without the library itself being loaded

Comment: @CapitanFindus    I am loading this code with Insert Headers and Footers plugin:

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.min.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2.2.1/dist/flickity.pkgd.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is due to the `defer` attribute on your flickity script:
[image]

your slider init code is inline in the `head` tag and fires as soon as its seen. because of the defer flickity is not available to your init call until the page is done loading.  Either remove the defer or wrap your init code in a dom ready call like below:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.main-carousel').flickity({
    // options
    cellAlign: 'left',
    contain: true
    });
});
```

here you can see if I re-add your init call in dev tools after the page has loaded the slider works:

[image]

Comment: Wow. I am that dumb. I used a plugin to defer JS for speed. Thanks a lot man :)

Comment: I have a quick quesiton if you can help me out here (trying with flickity). I have this code here. How can I make this like you made the above?
```(function($) {


    //abort if we're viewing inside builder
    if ($('html').attr('ng-app') == 'CTFrontendBuilder')
        return;

    var ids = {};
    $('.oxygen-body [id]').each(function() {
        if (this.id && ids[this.id]) {
            $(this).removeAttr('id');
        }
        ids[this.id] = 1;
    });

    $('.rep-carousel').flickity({
        cellSelector: '.rep-carousel-cell',
    });

})(jQuery);```

Comment: making sure i understand the question... are you just wanting this new code to fire on `ready` (after the page has finished loading)?

Comment: Happy to help!!

Comment: Well yeah no worries I managed to make this work :)